# Jquery Year Calendar Dates inputs not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using this 
http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Simple 
Boostrap year calendar. But when i call modal with inputs name even-start-date and event-end-date my modal wont work and throws the error i pasted at the bottom . Can someone help me in this regard? if i remove those date inputs the modal works fine

```
 function editEvent(event) {
$('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(event ? event.id : '');
$('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(event ? event.name : '');
$('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(event ? event.location : '');
$('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.startDate : '');
$('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.endDate : '');
$('#event-modal').modal();
 }

 function deleteEvent(event) {
  var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

   for(var i in dataSource) {
    if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
        dataSource.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}

$('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
}

   function saveEvent() {
  var event = {
    id: $('#event-modal input[name="event-index"]').val(),
    name: $('#event-modal input[name="event-name"]').val(),
    location: $('#event-modal input[name="event-location"]').val(),
       startDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-   date"]').datepicker('getDate'),
        endDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('getDate')
}

var dataSource = $('#calendar').data('calendar').getDataSource();

if(event.id) {
    for(var i in dataSource) {
        if(dataSource[i].id == event.id) {
            dataSource[i].name = event.name;
            dataSource[i].location = event.location;
            dataSource[i].startDate = event.startDate;
            dataSource[i].endDate = event.endDate;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    var newId = 0;
    for(var i in dataSource) {
        if(dataSource[i].id > newId) {
            newId = dataSource[i].id;
        }
    }

    newId++;
    event.id = newId;

    dataSource.push(event);
}

$('#calendar').data('calendar').setDataSource(dataSource);
$('#event-modal').modal('hide');
  }
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(function() {
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

$('#calendar').calendar({ 
    enableContextMenu: true,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    contextMenuItems:[
        {
            text: 'Update',
            click: editEvent
        },
        {
            text: 'Delete',
            click: deleteEvent
        }
    ],
    selectRange: function(e) {
        editEvent({ startDate: e.startDate, endDate: e.endDate });
    },
    mouseOnDay: function(e) {
        if(e.events.length > 0) {
            var content = '';

            for(var i in e.events) {
                content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">'
                                + '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>'
                                + '<div class="event-location">' + e.events[i].location + '</div>'
                            + '</div>';
            }

            $(e.element).popover({ 
                trigger: 'manual',
                container: 'body',
                html:true,
                content: content
            });

            $(e.element).popover('show');
        }
    },
    mouseOutDay: function(e) {
        if(e.events.length > 0) {
            $(e.element).popover('hide');
        }
    },
    dayContextMenu: function(e) {
        $(e.element).popover('hide');
    },
    dataSource: [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Google I/O',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
            location: 'New Orleans, LA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 16),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 19)
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Microsoft Build Developer Conference',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 3, 29),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 1)
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Apple Special Event',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 1)
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Apple Keynote',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 8, 9)
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Chrome Developer Summit',
            location: 'Mountain View, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 18)
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'F8 2015',
            location: 'San Francisco, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 25),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 2, 26)
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Yahoo Mobile Developer Conference',
            location: 'New York',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 25),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 7, 26)
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            name: 'Android Developer Conference',
            location: 'Santa Clara, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 1),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 11, 4)
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            name: 'LA Tech Summit',
            location: 'Los Angeles, CA',
            startDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17),
            endDate: new Date(currentYear, 10, 17)
        }
    ]
});

$('#save-event').click(function() {
    saveEvent();
});
 });

 });



    </script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'empty' of undefined
>       at Datepicker._updateDatepicker (ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:7976:13)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (hui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:9256:5)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370:19)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137:17)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.datepicker (ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:9253:14)
>       at editEvent (production/calendar.php:246:54)
>       at HTMLDivElement.selectRange (/production/calendar.php:321:13)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:5226:27)
>       at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878:28)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery-1.12.4.js:5130:12)

Comment: typo (the tab or spaces) here? 
`startDate: $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-   date"]').datepicker('getDate'),`

Comment: lol no that was by mistake there is not extra space in my actual code. the problem lies in datepicker i guess but i am unable to figure out :(

Comment: Ok ;-) Did you try to set the date manually instead of reading it from your event.startDate and so on? may be the date format differs?

Comment: i figured out the problem.it is with this line

$('#event-modal input[name="event-end-date"]').datepicker('update'); the update in datepicker function is not working properly

Comment: Sure - that's what the error says. Did you try to set it manually like [Explained here in the docs of datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: And what you probably want to do is to 1.) get the startDate that you want to set, than 2.) set it using datepicker setDate method

Comment: finally i figured it out. The problem was with 
 $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('update',event ? event.startDate : ''); 
so i changed it to

 $('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('setDate',event ? event.startDate : ''); 

and it worked 8-) .any way thanks for your previous time :)

Comment: well...that's exactly what I was pointing to => use the setDate and set startDate - so please mark my answer as being the correct one

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('update', event ? event.startDate : '');` you will have to use the setDate Method like so `$('#event-modal input[name="event-start-date"]').datepicker('setDate', event ? event.startDate : '');`

Comment: @Umeriqbal and now simply ACCEPT This answer as being the correct one :-D

Comment: @AlexOdenthal has spent time to answer your question Umer. The least you could do I mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it involved downloading or getting the cdn links to the following JavaScript and CSS resources (these are the names not the links):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css">

<script src="bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```